# Using Image Transform as another custom field

Tags: assets, image

I've created a section with a thumbnail image and also a dropdown to allow the user to select the transformation to apply to that image.

I've pre-created all the asset transformations ready and this is the code I have :

```
{% set imageTransform = storyEntry.storyThumbnailTransform %}
{% set thumbnailImage = storyEntry.storyThumbnail.first() %}
<img src="{{thumbnailImage.url(imageTransform) }}" alt="" class="post__preview-img post__preview-img--grid">
```

However, it doesn't appear to be rendering the image. If I output `storyEntry.storyThumbnailTransform` to the page, it displays the value of the image transform as expected.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `imageTransform` value is actually an object, representing the entire dropdown field.

Update the first line to this...

```
{% set imageTransform = storyEntry.storyThumbnailTransform.value %}
```

This will ensure that the selected **value** is passed on, instead of the full object.

(The reason that you see the proper value when you output it directly is because the object's `__toString` method is automatically being called internally.)

Comment: Lindsey, could this be used for custom image transforms set on the page? I'm getting the error that says that image transform is not available (and it is available if I type in verbatim).

Comment: @JohnJohnson Hard to say without looking at your code. I'd recommend [asking a brand new question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)... feel free to link back to this thread if relevant.

Comment: @LindseyD here is the question: https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/20873/user-selected-image-transform

Answer (score 0):

Do you not still have to do:

```
        {% for asset in thumbnailImage %}
            <img src="{{ asset.getUrl(imageTransform) }}" alt="" class="post__preview-img post__preview-img--grid">
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: No need for a loop, because they've already got it narrowed down to the `first` thumbnail image. Also `.getUrl` and `.url` are interchangeable (`url` is just an alias).